# Listboxitems, keep first index fixed and all the rest to scroll

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox for which I want to keep the first index fixed and all the rest to scroll. I am using WPF Technology.
Can anyone help me please. Thanks

I am using two different template for binding.
Here is my code.

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding isEnable}"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <CompositeCollection>
                <CollectionContainer x:Name="collection_item_data" />
                <CollectionContainer x:Name="dbCollection" />
            </CompositeCollection>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>

        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EBS:SingleItem}" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="stk">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" TextBlock.Foreground="White">
                        <StackPanel.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
                                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD3F1F9" Offset="0" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF70AED7" Offset="0.991" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </StackPanel.Background>
                        <TextBlock Width="160" Text="Item" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Style" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Brand" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Color" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Width="70" Text="Size" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Price" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />                            
                        <TextBlock Width="50" Text="Qty" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Tax" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="Total" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="2" TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel TextBlock.FontFamily="Rupee Foradian" x:Name="stk_add_item" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding dsItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Product_Name" SelectedValuePath="Product_Code"
                                   SelectionChanged="auto_item_SelectionChanged" x:Name="auto_item" Width="160" Margin="2" Loaded="auto_item_Loaded" >
                        </ComboBox>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="combo_style" Margin="2" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding DsStyle}" DisplayMemberPath="Style_Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectionChanged="combo_style_SelectionChanged" Loaded="combo_style_Loaded" />
                        <ComboBox x:Name="combo_brand" Margin="2" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding DsBrand}" DisplayMemberPath="Brand" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectionChanged="combo_brand_SelectionChanged" Loaded="combo_brand_Loaded" />
                        <ComboBox x:Name="combo_color" Margin="2" Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding dsColor}" DisplayMemberPath="Color_Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectionChanged="combo_color_SelectionChanged" Loaded="combo_color_Loaded" />                            
                        <ComboBox x:Name="combo_size" Margin="2" Width="70" ItemsSource="{Binding dsSize}" DisplayMemberPath="Size_Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectionChanged="combo_size_SelectionChanged" Loaded="combo_size_Loaded" />
                        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox Width="100" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="2" Watermark="Price" MaxLength="10" my2:TextBoxMaskBehavior.Mask="Decimal" my2:TextBoxMaskBehavior.MinimumValue="0" my2:TextBoxMaskBehavior.MaxLength="10" >
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding PriceString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="Control.IsFocused" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Price, StringFormat=F2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
                        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Quantity,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="50" Margin="2" Watermark="Qty" MaxLength="6" PreviewTextInput="WatermarkTextBox_PreviewTextInput" />
                        <Rectangle Fill="White" Height="26" Margin="2" Width="100" />
                        <xctk:WatermarkTextBox TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding TotalString,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="130" Margin="2" Watermark="Total" IsReadOnly="True" IsReadOnlyCaretVisible="True" KeyDown="WatermarkTextBox_KeyDown" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type EBS:Items}">
                <StackPanel IsEnabled="{Binding isEnable}" TextBlock.FontFamily="Rupee Foradian" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" Margin="2"  Width="160" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Style_Name}" Margin="2" Width="100" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Brand_Name}" Margin="2" Width="100" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Color_Name}" Margin="2" Width="100" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Size}" Margin="2" Width="70" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PriceString}" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="2" Width="100" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="2" Width="50" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tax, StringFormat=F2}" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="2" Width="100" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalString}" TextAlignment="Right" Margin="2" Width="130" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>

    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't if this could be achieved with a single listbox but You could make your scenario work if you use two listboxes one below the other (Bit of a heck).

just make one more listbox above the listbox you have currently using. resources are going to be same for both (but obvious!)

Somthing like this.

```
<Stackpanel>
<Listbox name="lb1"/> 
<Listbox name="lb2"/>
</Stackpanel>
```

And assign 1st item of the list in lb1 and rest of the list as an item source to lb2, and make lb1 vertically unscrollable

thats how we make a listbox horizontally, vertically unscrollable

```
<Listbox name="lb1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```